# How can I determine the last value of a field given some predefined conditions using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

| Track | Surface | HorseId | FGrating | New FGrating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 110 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 124 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 118 | -1 |
| Happy Valley | Grass | 1736 | 117 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 13973 | 144 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 13973 | 137 | -1 |

I want to fill the `New FGrating` column with the last FGrating of every horse only if the track is Sha Tin and the surface is Grass. The rest of the columns can remain -1. The result that I am looking for is this:

| Track | Surface | HorseId | FGrating | New FGrating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 110 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 124 | 110 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 1736 | 118 | 124 |
| Happy Valley | Grass | 1736 | 117 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 13973 | 144 | -1 |
| Sha Tin | Grass | 13973 | 137 | 144 |

For this, I tried to extract the required data intro a dataframe called `temp`. The code I used is this:

```
temp = featured_data.loc[(featured_data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (featured_data.Surface == 'Gress')]
temp = temp[['HorseId', 'FGrating']]
temp = temp.groupby('HorseId')
temp['New FGrating'] = temp['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

The only problem this code has is that at the `temp=temp.groupby('HorseId')` line, the entire 'HorseId' column disappears.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `temp=temp.groupby('HorseId')` groupby returns a Groupby Object, no DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check it myself at the moment but I think you can try it like this:

```
temp = featured_data.loc[(featured_data.Track == 'Sha Tin') & (featured_data.Surface == 'Grass')]
temp = temp[['HorseId', 'FGrating']]
temp['New FGrating'] = temp.groupby('HorseId')['FGrating'].apply(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

I think it is only a typo but you filtered for 'Gress' instead of 'Grass in your code example

Comment: It worked. But why? And yes, it is a typo.